# Redirect vim.stackexchange.com to vi.stackexchange.com

Tags: feature-request, status-completed

Someone who looks for a Stack Exchange website about Vim may type `vim.stackexchange.com` directly into the URL bar of their browser. This will get an unhelpful page saying that no such Stack Exchange site exists. Since [Vi and Vim Stack Exchange](https://vi.stackexchange.com) does exist, I propose that the former redirect to the latter.

Comment: But you get to see a picture of a cute panda bear!

Comment: I've actually thought that `vim` should be the main (maybe only) subdomain for the site. Correct me if I'm wrong, but these days isn't it practically *impossible* to use the original vi? Even when you enter `vi` on your system, it's usually an alias to `vim` set to behave differently.

Comment: @tommcdo Arch Linux ships with the 'original vi' by default. All the BSD systems ship with `nvi` by default. I believe most 'enterprise UNIX' systems such as Solaris, HP-UX, IRIX, etc. also ship with their own vi flavours. In addition, there are a number of other vi-clones one could use, such as elvis, vile, etc.... It's true that Vim is by far the most popular vi clone around, but willthis still be the case in 5 or 10 years? Perhaps. Perhaps not. Especially on the desktop, `s/prog1/prog2/` can happen quite fast...

Comment: @Carpetsmoker, fair point, I'll take it.

Answer (score 8):

Not sure when this was added, but http://vim.stackexchange.com currently  redirects to http://vi.stackexchange.com :-)